# Запись математического выражения

Tags: пунктуация

ищу и нигде не могу найти ответ. Может вы сможете помочь? Как по правилам русского языка правильно записывать выражения ( проверьте правильность написания окончаний и нужна ли запятая) и как сделать синтаксический разбор такого предложения? В первую очередь что является грамматической основой? К ПЯТИ ПРИБАВИТЬ ДВА, РАВНО СЕМИ.

Comment: К ПЯТИ ПРИБАВИТЬ ДВА РАВНО СЕМИ.

Answer (score 1):

***К пяти прибавить два  равно  семи.***

1. **Другие варианты** для сравнения (синтаксическая синонимия):

***Если** к пяти прибавить два, **то** будет семь.* СПП с придаточным **условия.**

*К пяти прибавить два — **будет** семь.* **БСП** (бессоюзная связь).

*К пяти прибавить два **равно** семи*. Простое предложение.

2. **Синтаксический** разбор

***К пяти прибавить два равно семи.***

Простое двусоставное предложение.

(1) ***Прибавить*** — подлежащее, выраженное инфинитивом.

(2) ***Равно*** — сказуемое, выраженное предикативным наречием.

Русский орфографический словарь:
***равно***, нареч. и в знач. сказ.

(3) ***К пяти, два, семи*** — дополнения, выраженные числительными.